# Unmarshall field to an Enum - possible?

Tags: enums, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have an xml document that holds a list of Car objects. Inside each Car object, it has elements Owner and Mechanic. Both Owner and Mechanic have exactly the same fields (Name and postcode). I want to unmarshal the Car objects into a list of Cars. Instead of having 2 sub-objects called Owner and Mechanic, I'd like to create one called Person. Inside person I'd like to indicate what type of person they are, either Owner or Mechanic. I created an Enum called PersonType holding Owner and Mechanic. Inside Car, I have put a variable called PersonType to differentiate. The PersonType is always null.

Can any help me to achieve this goal? I really think 2 objects for Owner and Mechanic is unnecessary.

Comment: Can you post your object model to the question?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I've figured out now that I don't need to do what I had planned. But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Eclipse MOXy's @XmlPath attribute and it worked a treat.